# Need to update column based on incoming value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, case

How can I achieve below scenario? I have below table structure:

```
 ----------------------------
| ID | COL_1 | COL_2 | COL_3 |
 ----------------------------
```

I have a scenario where I need to update the above table something like -

```
Update <table_name>
set decode (FILE_TYPE,'ABC',COL_1,
                      'CDE',COL_2,
                      'EFG',COL_3) = 'Y'
where ID = 12345;
```

Please note that FILE_TYPE column is flowing from upstream job. How can I select column name on the run? Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically choose which column to update, but you can instead perform several conditional assignments, like:

```
update mytable
set 
    col_1 = decode(file_type, 'ABC', 'Y', col_1),
    col_2 = decode(file_type, 'CDE', 'Y', col_2),
    col_3 = decode(file_type, 'EFG', 'Y', col_3)
where id = 12345
```

Only the column where the parameter matches the target value is updated - otherwise, the original value is reassigned (so that's a no-op).

It may be simpler to follow using `case` expressions:

```
update mytable
set 
    col_1 = case when file_type = 'ABC' then 'Y' else col_1 end,
    col_2 = case when file_type = 'CDE' then 'Y' else col_1 end,
    col_3 = case when file_type = 'EFG' then 'Y' else col_1 end,
where id = 12345
```